# SetCookie неправильно устанавливается время жизни

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Авторизация на сайте написана с использованием Cookie.

```
SetCookie ('Login',    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login']),time() + 1800);
```

Несколько месяцев всё работало нормально, и вдруг начались проблемы, у некоторых пользователей неправильно стало устанавливаться время жизни кук. Т.е. получалось, что куки вообще тут же удалялись после установки. Если удалить установку времени жизни, то всё начинает работать. Не подскажете, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: " вообще тут же удалялись после установки." - а может быть такое, что у пользователей они вообще отключены? вы делаете проверку на это?

Comment: нет, не может, потому что раньше всё работала, и если не устанавливать время жизни кук, то тоже всё работает

Comment: ведь от установок времени на клиентских машинах время жизни куки зависеть не должно?

Answer (score 1):

От установок - нет, а от значения - да.

Время на сервере проверьте, в первую очередь.

А вообще, это делают обычно наоборот. Саму куку - делают "до закрытия браузера", а уже на сервере, в сессии пишут время выполнения последнего обращения, и если от последнего обращения прошло много времени - закрывают сессию.

Comment: Спасибо! Время на сервере правильное.